# Prove that for $|z| < R$, we have $\frac{|z|}{|z^2-n^2|} \leq \frac{R}{n^2-R^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

> Prove that for $|z| < R$, we have $\frac{|z|}{|z^2-n^2|} \leq \frac{R}{n^2-R^2}$, where $n$ is an integer
>   greater than $R$.

This is from page 168, Lang's Complex Analysis. I am having trouble verifying this. Certainly, we have that $|n-z| \geq n - |z| \geq n-R$, but since $|z| \geq |z+n|-n \not\geq R$ I am not sure what to do.

Comment: That's wrong if $n \le R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
|z^2-n^2|\geq \left|n^2-|z|^2\right| \geq n^2-R^2
\end{align}